# Access php object without creating a variable?

Tags: php, object

right now I have:

```
$image = get_field('image');
```

If I `var_dump($image);`
Data returned will look like this:

```
Array
(
[id] => 540
[alt] => A Movie
[title] => Movie Poster: UP
[caption] => sweet image
[description] => a man and a baloon
[url] => http://localhost:8888/acf/up.jpg

)
```

If I want to access the title I would do:

```
$image['title'];
```

what if I want to access it directly wiithout a variable like:

```
get_field('image')['title'];
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasted directly from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

**Example #7 Array dereferencing**

```
<?php
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
?>
```

So yes - you can - but you need PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is possible since `PHP 5.4`.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php (check for point number 3)

All you have to do is just update version of you php :)

Answer (score 1):

You said object, but your example is an array.

Anyway it's called array dereference, and as Jari said has been possible since php 5.4.

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.